# Ways to arrange ALGEBRA so AA occurs

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

So the permutations of this qould be 7!, and I know that there are 2 objects of type A, but how can we isolate the events where those objects occur consecutively?

Comment: One approach is to look at all the permutations of $LGEBR$ and then insert $AA$ into the $6$ possible places (in between letters and at the ends)

Answer (score 6):

Arrange ZLGEBR, then replace Z with AA.